# discord.py: if ctx.author = guild.roles

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a command that allows specific users to block everyone.
I don't know how to write the if to make sure that if the author of the command is of that role he can read it (I'm doing this because I would like to impose different limits on certain roles).
At the same time I would like the user who executes the command to be given a user permission where he can write (this command is useful for my server when it is necessary to make important and immediate speeches.)
How could I do?

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'Guild' is not defined
```

Code:

```
@client.command(aleases=["Templock","TEMPLOCK","tl","Tl","TL"])
@commands.has_any_role('Moderatori', 'Triumvirato', 'Co-Triumvirato')
async def templock(ctx, seconds = 0, *,arg="Motivo non specificato"):
    channel_ability_mention = ctx.channel.mention
    channel_ability_name = ctx.channel.name
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    if not seconds:
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica il tempo!",
            icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
    if ctx.author == Guild.roles(name='Triumvirato'):
        if seconds > 600:
            embed.set_author(
                name="Hai superato il limite stabilito per i Triumviri!",
                icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png"
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
            return
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0x03c03c
        )
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback log.   Though I hazard a guess is that you haven't defined what Guild is.  Is it supposed to be imported from somewhere?  Is it a class?

Comment: File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc

Comment: perhaps add the traceback to the original post?  It's hard to read tracebacks in comments.

Comment: OMG true ... sorry I'm 6 in the morning I'm a little tired

Comment: You need to define Guild

Comment: where do I define it specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you didn't defined `Guild`, if you want the server the command was invoked, you need to replace `Guild.roles` to `ctx.guild.roles`.

Then, the way you get the `triumvirato` role is wrong, you can get it by id or by name this way:

```py
#by id
triumvirato = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)

#by name
triumvirato = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Triumvirato")
```

Finally, `ctx.author` is a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object, not a [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role) object, so your if statement will never be `True`. To make it work, you'll have to replace this line:

```py
if ctx.author == Guild.roles(name='Triumvirato'):
```

To this:

```py
if triumvirato in ctx.author.roles:
```